# Why islam is considered as "only" "one" "true" path, whereas nature provides multiple reasons to believe otherwise?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis, knowing-islam

I have started studying Islamic texts and thus multiple questions are coming in my mind? I am asking just for clarification and the thought process behind, there is no ill intention.

My observation throughout my life is: In nature for a single species multiple variants are present, even in man made systems for a single problem multiple variant of solutions are present. and even while thinking we choose between multiple options to carry forward our thought process. Then why Islam ( or any abhramic religion) focuses on keywords like " only", "one" and "true"? From where this inspiration comes as in why we blatantly ignore self experiences i.e. our own empirical experiences and focus more on given text i.e. is there a proof based logic in Islamic text where self experience is considered as lower than scriptures? I mean to say even when I am feeling pain in certain condition, do I need to search for a text which "may be" opposite to that feeling.

Take for example in general daily life as per my experience, valid sources of knowledge are from  as below in descending order:

1. Self experiences /empirical evidence
2. Inferences ( previous or similar empirical exp  behind it)
3. Analogy or comparison ( previous or similar empirical exp  behind it)
4. Words from a "trust-able" source ( previous empirical exp  behind it as trust is based on empirical exp)

Now what I believe all the three sources(2,3,4) of valid knowledge can be negated by empirical experiences like the example of pain I have given. Whereas in Islam, my observation is otherwise i.e. Least form of valid source of knowledge is considered as best , but I believe there must be some evidence based logic ( logic comes in inference which is again dependent on empirical exp) behind it. Requesting you to please clarify.

Please help me with query, I will be really thankful for these as it may help me to understand the Islam better.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Islam being true is a statement about reality. Personal feelings have little to do with it. Either the earth orbits the earth or it doesn't. Just like that, there is one God who chose Muhammad (SAW) as his last prophet. There aren't multiple versions of reality.

Comment: But why it is "true". What is the definition of truth here? And the personal feeling comes in picture when I see tag of "only one path" as"true" while other not i.e. to say when I have to go from point Signapore to point Newyork , either I can go directly, or with stops, or toward west or via toward east. I can chose my path as per my choice and condition, but when you say there is only true one path, it restricts me to choose that but nature or reality doesn't work in this way. You can have water from multiple sources based on your condition not only one source.

Comment: It isn't a matter of path, it is a matter of reality itself. There are no two realities. Either there is one God or there isn't one God. Either idol-worship is useless or it isn't. Either the Quran is from God, or it isn't. There are no two ways about it.

Comment: So my question is what does true means and why it is not in accordance with empirical experiences i.e. the way nature or reality is? Reality is subjective in nature, for me one person can be good or for you that same person can be bad. My reality is based on my subjective empirical exp but when you say that that what i believe in i.e. my subjective exp is objectively true and the person in question is objectively good one then you are negating my subjective and treating me just as an object. I hope you get my question i.e. in plain simple words What is the logic of "true", "only" and "one"?

Comment: Your comment is based on two valued logic and logic is cultural thing not universal. When you put four value logic which is predominantly used in Indian culture  there can be four options e.g. idol worship is bad, or idol worship is good, or idol worship is may be bad or may be good, or idol worship is neither bad nor good. Thus how one culture logic is true and others are not?

Comment: The question is not of "good" and "bad" which one could argue are subjective. The question is of "existence" or "non-existence." Question is about reality, not value. Value may be subjective. Reality is not. There is either one God or there is not one God.

Comment: I am also talking about reality, not about values or good or bad, or existence etc. Reality is also subjective not just values, for example how you are perceiving this question and how I am perceiving is also different, thus my reality is different from you. The possibility about god can also be many like there can be one, none, two, many, or combination of all or neither.

Comment: Why fixation on "one", "only" and "true"? even when we as single being feels doubtful because of multiple options as nature provide multiple options, even when in a family every other person see the world in different way? Why fixation with "only one way" and choosing two valued system of logic? When nature is just opposite to it?

Comment: Reality is unique, our perceptions and interpretations of reality might be different, but that doesn't change reality. Maybe if you could explain what confusing for you behind the idea of "one" in a practical manner. Not sure what the goal of the question.
Where do you see a difference between Islamic teachings and nature?

Comment: hmmm. How you are sure that reality is unique what is the evidence and based on what sources?

Comment: I have very simple question why Islam CLAIMS "only" "one" "path" and "only" "one" "god"? Why the use of "only" whereas there are multiple cultures and multiple paths, if one Islamic god is responsible for only one path who created other paths? Most of the people on this stack exchange are asking is it haram or halal, whereas this completely takes away ones ability to judge ones own situation but rely on something which is based on exemption that "there is only one way/reality etc and all other ways are created by satan" which by inference means islamic satan is more creative than islamic god?

Comment: Even if we agree on that statement by you " Reality is unique, our perceptions and interpretations of reality might be different, but that doesn't change reality." I may ask the same question if perception can be and are different than why Islam claims itself as "only" " one" "true" path? If you say it concerns with one reality then how you are sure about it that islam is talking about THE REALITY and why? is it just because of claim by one person and that too without any evidence?

Answer (score 3):

Truth is not subjective. Something is either true, or it is not.

Your four-point criteria, on the other hand, *is* subjective. You may use it to decide what you choose to believe or disbelieve about the world around you, but that has no bearing on what is *actually* true. Everything from self experiences, inferences, analogy and trustable sources can be misunderstood, misapplied or downright wrong. And there are many elements of this world that simply can't be determined with such a limited mindset.

It really wasn't too long ago that your exact same criteria would've had you believing in geocentricism, or alchemy, or spontaneous generation, or any number of common (pseudo)scientific theories of past ages that are no longer considered valid.

It is a fallacy to decide that something that is directly observable is "more true" than something that is not; if you choose to reject *[al-ghaib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Ghaib)* ("The Unseen") simply because you can't observe it, or deduce it, or trust anybody who reports on it, that's on you.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. My question is related to Islam "ClAIM" of "ONLY" and "one" and "true" and "path"? Further re have you heard of QFT which is based on four valued logic and how concept of reality is changing in quantum sciences which outright totally denies and refute two valued logic like "Truth is not subjective. Something is either true, or it is not" ?  I agree there can be al-ghaib, no refutation for that.

Comment: @Ablex I have provided an answer according to Islamic perspective, as per the scope of this site. If you're looking for expertise in quantum physics or alternate models of logic, there are other sites where those are in scope, but this is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't answer the question. I am not looking for expertise in quantum physics here, I am just clarifying with you that truth cant be defined by two valued logic or any logic systems. Animal has diff form of truth, every culture have diff form of truth, truth manifest in millions forms. Just my question is why Islam claims and consider itself as only one true path and negates other forms in totality whereas everything manifest in multiple forms e.g. even one person act differently in diff situations. Why focus on keywords "only" "one" and "true"?

Comment: Further are you saying Islam perspective is bound in just two valued logic and can't fathom or acknowledge other logic systems?

Comment: @Ablex You're right: The truth cannot be defined by two valued logic or any logic systems. Logic is simply a method by which people find the truth, it does not define it. **The truth itself either *is*, or *is not*,** and your insistence in bringing in alternate logic systems is entirely tangential to that point. Islam teaches that the truth, the right path, is clear, and my answer demonstrates the weaknesses in your criteria for finding that truth. Without addressing those, no answer I or anyone else can give will satisfy you.

Answer (score 0):

@Ablex I completely agree with you on the fact that our perceptions of reality are subjective and generally guided by our empirical experiences but the argument that these perceptions should be our independent guides to how we live falters in a society, which needs consensus and if everyone followed their own paths no society could function.

This is the same logic why we have certain generalised laws in countries, that prohibit lets say murder even though a certain unfortunate person might’ve grown up in an environment of crime and thus informing his perspective that taking someone’s life is not ‘bad’.

And also there is only ‘one’ set of laws in a country to keep people from forming their own ones and maintain order in society.

In Islam, our fundamental unquestionable belief is that there is only one God and that is Allah and He is the supreme entity and the ultimate authority. So it logically follows that to keep the entire civilisation from crumbling, the laws (which comprehensively teach us even interpersonal relations and individual morality) should be dictated by this highest authority that is Allah. Belief in the ‘one true path’ is basically belief in one God. Hope that answers your question:)

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification for the purposes of improving the post they're on, not for argument and debate or extended discussion of tangential points. If the relevant posts are unclear to the point that you need extensive discussion to explain how it answers the question, chances are the post needs to be edited.